# Ionic Serve doesn't work properly?

Tags: javascript, angular, web, ionic-framework, frameworks

Ionic server doesn't work properly
[image: Ionic server doesn't work properly]

why doesn't it display it properly? Is it Ionics fault or my browser (Google Chrome)

Comment: remove the `href link` for `main.css`

Comment: it didn't work, no changes at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a problem with the actual `@ionic/app-scripts` version.
You need to downgrade your app-scripts version like so: `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@1.3.7 --save-dev`

See here: [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12442)

Comment: so I just installed that npm package and its all set?

Comment: It should work right after it, it is not a problem related to ionic itself, it is more related to the app scripts in particular. Maybe you need to remove the `node_modules` folder first and reinstall it with `npm install`.